# On Ways to Show that the Cardinalities of $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are the Same?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

"Everyone knows" that to show that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountably infinite, it suffices to show that the real numbers in the interval $(0,1)$ cannot be listed, which can be accomplished by Cantor's famous *diagonal argument.*

My question is: How may I prove that the cardinalities of these two sets are the same? Is it only possible to show this by finding a bijection from one of these sets into another? Are there other ways?

Comment: One minor variation on the existence of a bijection you see a lot is showing there is an injection $(0,1)\to\mathbb R$ and an injection $\mathbb R\to (0,1)$, from which a bijection can be constructed via the Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein theorem. Here it's easiest to just use the arctan function to get an explicit bijection, though.

Comment: You can also do it with explicit functions; consider the fact that $\arctan(x)$ establishes a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, and then use a simple linear function to show that $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ is bijecatable with $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you find a bijection between them to show both cardinalities are same. But here, even if you don't know the explicit map (bijection), between $\Bbb R$  and $(0,1)$, we can still say both are equivalent via some geometrical notion. For example, see the below figure

[image]

The idea is : (replace $-1$ by $0$ in figure) Imagine $(0,1)$ bent into a semicircle that rests on the number line at $O$.  Rays from the center of the semicircle establish a one-to-one correspondence between points of $(0, 1)$ and points of the line.

Answer (score 3):

By definition,  showing two sets have the same cardinality means showing there exists a bijection between them.

To this end, $\arctan x$ can be used.  That is,  $\arctan:\Bbb R\to (-\frac {\pi}2,\frac {\pi}2)$ is a bijection.

So we just need a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(-\frac {\pi}2,\frac {\pi}2)$.  But this is easy.   Let $c(t)=(1-t)(-\frac {\pi}2)+t(\frac {\pi}2)$.