# Prove that there exist equal number of irrational numbers between any 2 rational numbers, when the difference between the 2 rational numbers is same.

Tags: proof-writing, real-numbers, infinity, infinite-groups

> Prove that there exist equal number of irrational numbers between any 2 rational numbers, when the difference between the 2 rational numbers is same.

If the assertion is not true then please prove otherwise.

Comment: It (perhaps) depends on what you mean by **equality**.  Since the irrational (and rational) numbers are **dense** in $~\Bbb{R},~$ for any two  distinct rational numbers, there will always be an infinite number of irrational numbers between them.  Further, infinity is not a number but is instead a symbol of unbounded growth.  So, given the distinct rational numbers $~a_1 < ~a_2, ~$ and the positive number $~r,~$ I surmise that you are being asked to demonstrate a bijection between the irrational numbers in $~(a_1, ~a_2),~$ and the irrational numbers in $~(a_1 + r, ~a_2 + r).$

Comment: As phrased, the question is imprecise:  what does it mean for two intervals to contain the "same number" of irrational numbers?  The usual way to make this precise is to talk about "cardinality", instead.  In terms of cardinality, a [stronger statement is true](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1434479/).

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4427283/, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/783020/, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3305186/, etc.  A Google search like `all intervals have the same cardinality site:math.stackexchange.com` will return more related results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a nice proof of a much stronger theorem which is that there exist equal numbers of irrational numbers between any 2 distinct real numbers (even if the difference between the two numbers isn't the same).

To prove this, consider 2 line segments in the cartesian plane `s1` and `s2`. The first is from `P1=(s_1, 0)` to `P2=(e_1, 0)`, and the other from `P3=(s_2, 1)` to `P4=(e_2, 1)`. Draw lines L1 and L2 which connect P1 to P3 and P2 to P4 respectively, and label their intersection P5. Now for any point `x` on `s1` we can draw the line connecting P1 to `x`. This line intersects `s2` at exactly one point, and it's fairly simple to prove that this forms a bijection between `s1` and `s2`.